# How to set ng-model-options in a custom directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Setting `controller.$options` in the `link` function seems to work for debouncing *blur* events:

```
controller.$options = {
  updateOn : 'blur',
  debounce : 3000
};
```

...but if I try the same for *default* events, the model is never updated:

```
controller.$options = {
  updateOn : 'default',
  debounce : 3000
};
```

When using the `ng-model-options` directive instead, everything works as expected.

See http://plnkr.co/edit/KLrSrs2Jw7pkoAUNRJDf?p=preview

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Looking at the [source of the ngModelOptions directive](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/d21dff21ed8beb015ad911f11d57cceb56fc439f/src/ng/directive/input.js#L3089), it appears that instead of setting `updateOn : 'default'`, you need to set `controller.$options.updateOnDefault = true;`

Comment: and again you need to look at the source code, oh thank you guys! great API docs

Answer (score 19):

for your case you could try

```
ngModelController.$options = {
    updateOn: 'blur',
    updateOnDefault: true,
    debounce: {
      'blur': 2000,
      'default': 3000
    }
  };
```

but now (ng1.6+) you must do it like (read more [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$overrideModelOptions), [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/12884#issuecomment-318285703), and [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ModelOptions)):

```
ngModelController.$overrideModelOptions({
    updateOn: 'blur',
    updateOn: 'default',
    debounce: {
      'blur': 2000,
      'default': 3000
    }
});
```